# Is there a Python function equivalent to Gamma[a, z] in Mathematica?

Tags: python, math, wolfram-mathematica

I believe the incomplete Gamma function implemented in Mathematica is equivalent to an unregularized version of the upper gamma function.. The Gamma incomplete function as implemented in scipy is a regularized lower gamma function.. However, I may be wrong as my knowledge in this area is zero. I need to compute an equivalent of the incomplete gamma function from Mathematica in Python

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

The `scipy.special` module contains an implementation of both the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammainc.html#scipy.special.gammainc) `scipy.special.gammainc` and the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html#scipy.special.gammaincc) `scipy.special.gammaincc` (note the second c at the end)

`scipy` gives a scaled version of Mathematicas equivalent. If a>0 in `Gamma[a, x]` you should be able to use:

```
from scipy.special import gamma, gammaincc
gamma(0.01)*(gammaincc(0.01, 1))
# 0.22036593781812577
```

for the equivalent of `Gamma[0.01, 1]` in Mathematica.

[image]